# Is ethanol toxic to liver, in the absence of ethanol metabolites resulting from inhibiting alcohol dehydrogenase(ADH) enzyme?

Tags: alcohol, liver, drug-metabolism, recreational-drugs, alcoholism

Humans have been drinking alcohol for its intoxicating effects. For intoxication a small amount of alcohol is sufficient, but because the liver is very efficient in filtering it, we need more of it to get intoxicated.

This seems to be the main problem. This is what causes us to drink a lot to get high. This is also what causes liver damage over a long period of time and in short term this is what causes hangover.

This metabolic pathway changes if we coadminister lesser amount of alcohol with alcohol dehydrogenase (ADH) inhibitor like 4-methylpyrazole (4-MP) which slows down breaking of alcohol and one could achieve same amounts of intoxication with comparatively very less alcohol.

Apparently [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fomepizole) agrees with this, but **warns** that if the alcohol dose is not reduced then it may cause severe intoxicated and over dose.

> Concurrent use with ethanol is contraindicated because fomepizole is
> known to prolong the half-life of ethanol via inhibiting its
> metabolism. Extending the half-life of ethanol may increase and extend
> the intoxicating effects of ethanol, allowing for greater (potentially
> dangerous) levels of intoxication at lower doses. Fomepizole slows the
> production of acetaldehyde by inhibiting alcohol dehydrogenase, which
> in turn allows more time to further convert acetaldehyde into acetic
> acid by acetaldehyde dehydrogenase. The result is a patient with a
> prolonged and deeper level of intoxication for any given dose of
> ethanol, and reduced "hangover" symptoms (since these adverse symptoms
> are largely mediated by acetaldehyde build up

But also agrees that if the dose is adjusted and lowered it can have a positive effect.

> If alcoholics instead very carefully reduce their doses to reflect the
> now slower metabolism, they may get the "rewarding" stimulus of
> intoxication at lower doses with less adverse "hangover" effects -
> leading potentially to increased psychological dependency. **However,
> these lower doses may therefore produce less chronic toxicity and
> provide a harm minimization approach to chronic alcoholism**

Now **assuming** that alcoholics are placed under strict supervision and two groups are given with just alcohol and alcohol with 4-MP, to achieve comparable intoxication.

So if group A receives, say 15ml of pure alcohol containing beverage, then B receives 3ml or so, of alcohol along with 4-MP.

1. Can this help in the prevention of alcohol related liver complications?
2. Is 4-MP, despite it's short term safety, is safe for long term use?

Is there any data is medical literature on this?

---

Edit: Regarding the concerns about toxicity.

> According to Dr. Dasgupta's research, the perfect BAC in accordance
> with these moderate drinking guidelines is 0.04 - 0.05%. When your BAC
> is in this range, you feel good, you gain all the health benefits from
> the alcohol, and you should not appear overly impaired

So even if we assume none of the alcohol breaks down, average human has around 5000 ml of blood. Reverse calcuating it 2.5g of alcohol will cause a BAC of 0.05% which is ideal and non toxic. So if we give some one 3ml of ethanol with 4-MP, then theoretically it's completely safe.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you answered your own question. Lowering the threshold for intoxication lowers the threshold for toxicity. The likelihood of acute ethanol poisoning is increased by coadministering these drugs. Strict supervision is resource intensive and probably impractical for managing such a common condition.

In addition ethanol displays [nonlinear pharmacokinetics](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7004237/), meaning that once alcohol dehydrogenase is saturated there is metabolic autoinhibition of further alcohol breakdown - basically all the alcohol dehydrogenase is blocked up with alcohol slowing down breakdown.

This changes the breakdown of alcohol from [first order to zeroth order](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK499866/) according to the Michaelis Menten relationship which means that further increases in blood alcohol concentration do not affect the rate of the reaction.

[image: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Michaelis_Menten_curve_2.svg]
(Source: Wikimedia Commons)

Accordingly, if you have blocked alcohol dehydrogenase already the threshold for reaching zeroth order elimination is lower. When this happens there is effectively a "bottleneck" in the elimination of ethanol and it will accumulate much faster in the plasma.

---

With regard to your mention of health benefits to alcohol this is probably [not true.](https://www.cdc.gov/alcohol/fact-sheets/moderate-drinking.htm)

> Although past studies have indicated that moderate alcohol consumption has protective health benefits (e.g., reducing risk of heart disease), recent studies show this may not be true.6-11 While some studies have found improved health outcomes among moderate drinkers, it’s impossible to conclude whether these improved outcomes are due to moderate alcohol consumption or other differences in behaviors or genetics between people who drink moderately and people who don’t.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132851/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-o-maolain-is-ethanol-toxic-to-liver-in-the-absenc).

Comment: Brian did you read my comments? Please update the answer especially regarding liver health

Comment: I don't know the answer to your new question i.e. whether ethanol is directly hepatotoxic.